# Wifi Connection Failed (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

My Dell XPS 13 9360 was powered off for several months, battery completely died. I booted back up and couldn't connect to wifi anymore. No issues running Ubuntu for years. 18.04 currently on this device.

Connection Failed: Activation of network connection failed.

I thought it was hardware, so I swapped the OEM Killer M2 wifi chip for an Intel 9260. After various issues setting up the 9260, I'm having the same problem not connecting.

Bluetooth connects and functions fine with the Intel 9260.

Connection fails with my Wifi router and with my phone as a hotspot.

Connection also fails the same way on a fresh 19.04 usb drive, trying Ubuntu.

iwconfig

```
lo  no wireless extensions.
wlp58s0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any Mode:Managed  
Access Point:Not-Associated  Tx-Power=22dBm
Retry short limit:7  RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
```

While trying to connect, iwconfig adds:

```
Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid mixc:7  Missed beacon:0
```

It looks like the signal strength is good. GUI signal bars are full strength.

dmesg | grep wlp58s0

```
wlp58s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx
wlp58s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
wlp58s0: authenticated
wlp58s0: associate with xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
wlp58s0: associated
wlp58s0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

It looks like the connection is made, then immediately disconnects.

dmesg | grep iwl

```
iwlwifi: enabling device
iwlwifi: loaded firmware version 43.95eb4e97.0 op_mode iwlmvm
iwlwifi: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9260, REV=0x324
iwlwifi: base HW address: xx:xx:xx
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
iwlwifi: wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
```

So the latest drivers are being used.

lshw -class network

```
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless-AC 9260
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:3A00.0
logical name: wlp58s0
version: 29
serial: xx:xx:xx
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
Capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-13generic firmware=43.95eb4e97.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:16 memory:dc100000-dc103fff
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I've tried rebooting network-manager, restarting over and over, and a few other things I can't remember anymore.

It doesn't work with an 18.04 usb drive anymore, the same one I used to install 18.04 originally. It doesn't work with a 19.04 boot drive either.

I've been digging into this all day. There's no ethernet on this laptop, so I really need to get this working. Where do I go next?

Answer (score 1):

The bios date went from 2019 to January 2017 when the battery died. I updated the bios date to the correct date, 07/07/19. It still didn't work. I noticed the date on my desktop was 2119 somehow.

```
sudo date -s "7 Jul 2019 18:30:00"
```

And now I can connect to wireless.

I figured the date would self correct once I connected to the internet. I was wrong. It can't believe it was that simple.